# validating jstl sql datasource using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, sql, jstl, jsp-tags

I am trying to retrieve data from SQL query executed and validate the result with input I am making within form. I keep getting no return, in other words, it just returns empty value. Could you please help me with this matter or if this not the correct solution then how can I retrieve this value to perform validation.

My validation should match the inputed user with database user.

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["input"]["user"].value;
    var y = document.forms["input"]["pwd"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "" && y==null || y=="" ) {
     alert("Username and Password must be filled out");

        return false;
    }
}

function validateUser() {
    var x = document.forms["input"]["user"].value;
    var variableFromServer = "${names.FIRST_NAME}";
    document.write('<p>'+variableFromServer+'</p>');
    if (x != variableFromServer) {
     alert("Username is not right"+variableFromServer);

        return false;
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>


<sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:********" user="******" password="******"/>
Connected


<sql:query dataSource="${db}" var="query_select"> 
Select * from User_Details  
</sql:query>
<c:forEach var="names" items="${query_select.rows}" >

inside loop : <p>${names.FIRST_NAME}</p>
 </c:forEach>

 <form action= "/BilalWebtier/login.jsp" name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp"  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm() & validateUser();">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
<input type="submit" value="Login"> 

<br/>
<br/>
</form>



<button type="button">Password Reset</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the html output of this JSP.

Comment: it provides me with form, containing username and password. also provides me with first name within database which i am printing out.

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to the click event

```
<form action= "/BilalWebtier/login.jsp" name="input" action="demo_form_action.jsp"  method="post" >
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return validateForm() && validateUser();"> 

<br/>
<br/>
</form>
```

Comment: ive tried on click and it return alert upon clicking within field, it wont even allow me to input data